# Button INPUT that saves data and links at the same time

Tags: php, html, post, button

I'm doing a questionnaire (form) and I need to put a submit button that does two things:

1. Be a button type INPUT (because I need to use this kind of button on my PHP code, I've `if(@$_POST['Next'])` for save the dates of the form in my DB).
2. That this button will have a link for go to the next screen of the questionnaire. I tried with

   ```
   <a href="demo2.html" target="_blank">
       <input class="buttonNext" name="submit" type="submit" value="NEXT &#8592">
   </a>
   ```

This code doesn't work, but with IE browser, on the page appears a circle next to my button that is the link. So the button doesn't work; it only saves the data, but doesn't link to the next page.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The form's action determines the URL where the form is sent, and this is just good for you (it is sent to the PHP that processes this step). It can save the data and/or return the form again to show validation errors. Once you decide to go to the next step, you can redirect the user to that url.

Answer (score 0):

use `if(isset($_POST['Next'])){` instead of `@`

Comment: Even this is better way of checking if variable exists, **THIS DOESN'T ANSWER ORIGINAL QUESTION**.

Comment: true, i didnt understand the question, but thought I'd provide improvement on the code. sorry